# Operations based on conditional values from differents columns

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

My dataset is such, `Unitatsconsum_2021`:

```
structure(list(NUMERO = structure(c(15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 
19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    edat = c(41, 84, 53, 66, 65, 73, 72, 62, 60, 34, 54, 52, 
    24, 48, 12, 17), membres = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), groups = structure(list(
    NUMERO = structure(c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2:3, 4:5, 6:7, 8:10, 11:13, 14:16), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE))
```

And I want to create a new variable, say `unitats_consum`, which should be equal to:
1 + 0.5*((`membres` if `edat`>13)-1) + 0.3*(`membres` if `edat`>=13)
And the result should be shared by `NUMERO`, so each identical `NUMERO` should have the same `unitats consum`.

So far, I have tried this:

```
Despesa_unitatsconsum_2021 <- Despesa_membres_llar_2021 %>%
group_by(NUMERO) %>%
  mutate(unitats_consum = (1 + 0.5*((membres if edat > 13)-1) + 0.3*((membres if edat <= 13))))
```

I can't find which operator works as `if` and how this operatio can be grouped by `NUMERO`. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You may need `ifelse` or `case_when` i.e. `Despesa_membres_llar_2021 %>% mutate(unitats_consum = ifelse(edat > 13, 1 + 0.5 *(membres -1), 0.3 *(membres)))`

Answer (score 1):

To create the new variable 'unitats_consum', you can use the 'ifelse' statement within mutate function. But the condition must be indicated correctly:

```
Despesa_unitatsconsum_2021 <- Despesa_unitatsconsum_2021 %>%
  mutate(unitats_consum = 1 + 0.5 * ifelse(edat > 13, 
  membres - 1, 0) + 0.3 * ifelse(edat <= 13, membres, 0))

Despesa_unitatsconsum_2021


   edat membres unitats_consum
40   73       1            1.0
41   73       1            1.0
42   73       1            1.0
43   73       1            1.0
44   73       1            1.0
45   73       1            1.0
46   44       2            1.5
47   44       2            1.5
48   44       2            1.5
49   44       2            1.5
50   44       2            1.5
```